# Linear functional over complex sequences

Tags: functional-analysis

[image: problem]

My try:
At part (a) I can show that M is non-empty (giving explicit example) and convex (by definition). Problems appear when i try show it is bounded (i have no idea at all) and weak*-closed. At part (b) instructor said to use Markov-Kakutani fixed point theorem but i can't check all the conditions of it.

[image: problem]

I don't know how to prove (c).
If part (c) is proved i can prove (d).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Ad a): a mean is positive, and has $m(1) = 1$. Also, $4 = 1+1+1+1$. How might the hint relate to that?

Comment: The hint helps to show the set M is bounded by 4. I don't know how to distribute properties that hold only on real sequences to complex sequences.

Comment: I proved the set M is bouded in part (a). I represented sequence as sum of real sequence and purely complex sequence, and then each part represented as difference of positive sequences. So norm of elements in M do not exceed 4.

Comment: Good. That's exactly what the hint was for. Now you might want to spend some time to see if you can show that a mean actually has norm $1$, but that's not necessary. Have you any idea how to show that $\mathcal{M}$ is weak$^\ast$-closed?

Comment: Actually i have no idea(

Comment: $$\mathcal{M} = \varphi_1^{-1}(\{1\}) \cap \bigcap \left\lbrace \varphi_f^{-1}\bigl([0,\infty)\bigr) : f \in l_\infty(\mathbb{Z}),\, f \geqslant 0\right\rbrace$$ where $\varphi$ is the canonical embedding into the bidual, $\varphi_f(\lambda) = \lambda(f)$. So $\mathcal{M}$ is the intersection of weak$^\ast$-closed (convex) sets.

Answer (score 1):

a) Let $m$ be a mean. Every element  $a \in l_{\infty}(\mathbb{Z})$ with $\|a\| \leq 1$ can be decomposed as $a = a_1 - a_2 +i(a_3 - a_4)$ with $a_i \in l_{\infty}(\mathbb{Z}), a_i \geq 0 \text{ and } \| a\| \leq 1 $ for all $1\leq i\leq 4$. Just take $a_1 = $ positive real part of $a$, $a_2 = $ negative real part of $a$ and similarly for $a_3$ and $a_4$. Now $a_i\geq 0 $ and $a_i \leq 1 \implies 0\leq m(a_i)\leq 1$. Adding them up we get $|m(a)| \leq 4$ which shows $\|m\| \leq 4$.

c) It is enough to show for $A = \{1\}$. Let $B = \{1,2,..,n \}$. Now if $m$ is an invariant mean then $m(1_B) = n*m(1_A)$ . But $\|1_B\| \leq 1$ and so $|m(1_B)| \leq 4$. Hence $|m(1_A)| \leq 4/n$ for all $n$. Hence $m(1_A) = 0$. For odd integers, note that a translate of them is even integers and the fact that $m(1) = 1$. Hence you would get $1/2$. Using a similar logic you would get that $m(S) = 0$, by using the fact that the squares get sparse as $n$ increases and using $m(1_A) = 0$ for any finte set $A$.